# Two ways of calculating the expectation value of momentum

Tags: quantum-mechanics, homework-and-exercises, wavefunction, momentum, fourier-transform

The expectation value of momentum is given by:

$$
\langle p\rangle = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\psi^{*}(x)\left(-i\hbar\frac{\partial}{\partial x}\right)\psi(x)dx
$$

How can I show that the above expression is equivalent to this?
$$
\langle p\rangle = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty}p|\tilde\psi(p)|^{2}dp
$$

I have tried to use that

$$\psi(x)=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi\hbar}}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\tilde\psi(p)e^{ipx / \hbar}dp$$ 
and 
$$\psi^{*}(x)=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi\hbar}}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\tilde\psi^{*}(p)e^{-ipx / \hbar}dp$$

Then
$$
\langle p \rangle = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \left[\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi\hbar}}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\tilde\psi^{*}(p)e^{-ipx / \hbar}dp \right
]\left(-i\hbar\frac{\partial}{\partial x}\right
)\left[\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi\hbar}}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\tilde\psi(p)e^{ipx / \hbar}dp \right]dx$$
$$=\frac{1}{2\pi\hbar}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\left 
[ \left (\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \tilde\psi^{*}(p)e^{-ipx / \hbar}dp \right) 
(-i\hbar) \left (\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{\partial}{\partial x}\tilde\psi(p)e^{ipx / \hbar}dp \right)\right]dx$$
$$=\frac{1}{2\pi\hbar}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\left 
[ \left (\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \tilde\psi^{*}(p)e^{-ipx / \hbar}dp \right) 
(-i\hbar) \left (\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{ip}{\hbar}\tilde\psi(p)e^{ipx / \hbar}dp \right)\right]dx
$$

But I don't know if this is the right approach or if I'm doing the right thing.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you represent the wave function $\psi(x)$ with it's fourier transform,

\begin{eqnarray*}
\psi(x) &=& \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi \hbar}}\int \tilde{\psi}(p)e^{\frac{ipx}{\hbar}}dp\\
\psi(x)^\star &=& \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi \hbar}} \int \tilde{\psi}^\star(q)e^{\frac{-iqx}{\hbar}}dq
\end{eqnarray*}

(where p and q are almost like "dummy" momenta), then you can rewrite the expectation value of momentum as follows:

\begin{eqnarray}
\langle p \rangle &=& \int \psi^\star \left(-i\hbar \frac{\partial}{\partial x}\right)\psi dx\\
&=& \frac{1}{2\pi \hbar} \int \tilde{\psi}^\star(q)e^{\frac{-iqx}{\hbar}}\left(-i\hbar \frac{\partial}{\partial x}\right) \tilde{\psi}^\star(p)e^{\frac{ipx}{\hbar}} dpdqdx 
\end{eqnarray}

Now if you apply the derivative with respect to $x$, you'll spit out a $p$ in the integrand

\begin{eqnarray}
&=& \frac{1}{2\pi \hbar} \int \tilde{\psi}^\star(p) \tilde{\psi}^\star(q)e^{\frac{i(q-p)x}{\hbar}} \left(p\right) dpdqdx 
\end{eqnarray}

and exchanging integration order to integrate over $x$ first -- since we know these functions to be $L^2$ integrable --yields the (scaled) dirac delta function:

\begin{eqnarray}
&=& \frac{1}{2\pi \hbar} \int \tilde{\psi}^\star(p) \tilde{\psi}^\star(q)\hbar \delta(q-p) \left(p\right) dpdq \\
\langle p \rangle &=&\frac{1}{2\pi } \int \vert\tilde{\psi}(p)\vert^2 p dp
\end{eqnarray}

There's a missing factor of $2\pi$ in there, but I trust you'll find it if you do it carefully by hand.

Comment: Sorry, but where does $q$ come from?

Comment: p and q both mean momentum. When your first equation is rewritten, an expression with p is inserted in two places. You would not know which p goes with which integral. So one of the expressions was rewritten using q.

Answer (score 0):

I think that there's another way, without the (sometimes) dubious delta function, assuming the functions drop off rapidly toward infinity:
$$
\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\psi^{*}(x)\left(-i\hbar\frac{\partial}{\partial x}\right)\psi(x)dx\\
=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\psi^{*}(x)\left(-i\hbar\frac{\partial}{\partial x}\right)\int_{-\infty}\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi\hbar}}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\tilde\psi(p)e^{ipx / \hbar}dpdx\\
=\frac1{\sqrt{2\pi\hbar}}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\psi^{*}(x)\int_{-\infty}p \tilde\psi(p)e^{ipx / \hbar}dpdx\\
=\frac1{\sqrt{2\pi\hbar}}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}p\tilde\psi(p)\int_{\infty}^\infty
\psi^{*}(x)e^{ipx / \hbar}dxdp\\
=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}p\tilde\psi(p)
\left(\frac1{\sqrt{2\pi\hbar}}
\int_{\infty}^\infty
\psi(x)e^{-ipx / \hbar}dx\right)^*dp\\
=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}
p\tilde\psi(p)\tilde\psi^*(p)dp\\
=\langle p\rangle
$$